# Posting file to https server with aspx?

Tags: android, asp.net, file-upload, https, ssl-certificate

This is my code to send file to server over HTTP,
but i am trying to transfer using HTTPS i tried it for passing values using parameters it was working but i don't know how to code it with file stream,
can anybody help me with this i have ssl certificate

```
void Sending() {
        String iFileName = "video.mp4";
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";
        String Tag = "fSnd";
        try {
            Log.e(Tag, "Starting Http File Sending to URL");

            // Open a HTTP connection to the URL



            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) connectURL
                    .openConnection();          

            // Allow Inputs
            conn.setDoInput(true);

            // Allow Outputs
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            // Don't use a cached copy.
            conn.setUseCaches(false);

            // Use a post method.
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");

            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                    "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);

            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"title\""
                    + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(Title);
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"description\""
                    + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(Description);
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\""
                    + iFileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            Log.e(Tag, "Headers are written");

            // create a buffer of maximum size
            int bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

            int maxBufferSize = 1024;
            int bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            // read file and write it into form...
            int bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            while (bytesRead > 0) {
                dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            // close streams
            fileInputStream.close();

            dos.flush();

            Log.e(Tag,
                    "File Sent, Response: "
                            + String.valueOf(conn.getResponseCode()));

            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

            // retrieve the response from server
            int ch;

            StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer();
            while ((ch = is.read()) != -1) {
                b.append((char) ch);
            }
            String s = b.toString();
            Log.i("Response", s);
            dos.close();
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            Log.e(Tag, "URL error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }

        catch (IOException ioe) {
            Log.e(Tag, "IO error: " + ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
        }
    }
```